# Фильтрация ввода

Tags: c, c++

На вход поступает строка вида

```
234 sdfas
```

Требуется считывать только то слово, которые начинаются с цифры. Я пробую

```
scanf("%[1-9][a-zA-Z]s", input);
```

Но так не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что значит слово которое начинается с цифры ???

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char line[] = "234 sdfas", buf[256];
    int code = 0;
    sscanf(line, "%d %256s", &code, buf);

    //code == 234: - тут цифра 
    //buf - тут слово "sdfas"    
    return 0;
}
```

если у вас в этой строке код всегда из 3х цифр, то:

```
int main()
{
    char line[] = "234 sdfas";

    char* slovo = &line[4]; //slovo - тут слово "sdfas"

    line[3] = 0;  //line - тут цифра "234"

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Требуется считывать только то слово, которые начинаются с цифры

Напрямую из потока такой фильтр, конечно не написать, а вот просканировать буфер получится, и очень даже неплохо:

```
sscanf( input, "%*1[0-9]%*[^\x20]%n", &len );
sscanf( input, "%*[0-9]%*[a-zA-Z]%n", &chk );

if( len && chk && ( chk < len ) ){
  //  это слово, которое начинаются с цифры, но не число
}
```

Первая проверка определяет, что слово начинается с цифры и вычисляет его длину. Вторая проверка определяет, что в этом слове есть буквы.

\x20 - это пробел, сюда же можно добавить символы перевода строки (или просто поставить [^ ]).

Comment: Формализм в таком случае, требует еще добавить пробел в конце буфера, чтобы исключить попадание терминатора в фильтр.

Comment: подразумевается, что chk и len изначально инициализированы нулем

Answer (score 1):

Если вид строки всегда "число<пробел>строка", то можно считать нужной частью то, что находится до первого пробела. Тогда считывание можно организовать через поток с одновременным приведением к числу:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {

char* s = "123 abc";

stringstream ss;
ss<<s;

istream_iterator<int> i(ss);

int a = *i;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Идея такая

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
skip ()
{
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if ((unsigned)c > ' ')
      break;
  }
  return c;
}

int
main ()
{
  int  c;
  char word[1000];

  while ((c = skip()) != EOF) {
    if (isdigit(c)) 
      ungetc(c,stdin);
    if (scanf("%s",word) != 1)
      break;
    if (isdigit(c)) 
      puts(word);
  }
}
```